# How do I trigger an action on my application users' data sync on Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I need to trigger a check on the user data sync event of Amazon Cognito. How can I hook to the sync event?

I'd like to also enhance that data in some cases for the mobile application to fetch on next sync. Is the data editable from the server (not the mobile device)?

Comment: Does the sync data go to dynamoDB? can DynamoDB Streams be used to trigger a function in Lambda?

Comment: On further research, looks like Fine Grained Access Policy allows to write to DynamoDB with access restricted to user's data only using cognito-IDs as 'dynamodb:LeadingKeys' 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html

Comment: The 'writing to DynamoDB' part is covered in http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Cognito does not support triggers on sync data. If you would like to see this feature added, please request in our [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=173), that helps us to prioritize our roadmap.

Yes, you can edit the data using your AWS credentials (not one received from Cognito). Please refer to our [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cognito-update-sync-store-access-improved-console-more/) for more details.

Thanks,
Rachit

Comment: Thanks Rachit for the links. I've added a thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172772 . For now there is a workaround, to save data in DynamoDB instead and use DynamoDB Streams to trigger a lambda function. Cognito clients can write to DynamoDB record as shown in http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Cognito Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-streams/)  is now available to all and is the best way to trigger an action on CognitoSync. This requires creating a Kinesis Stream and then edit the Cognito Identity Pool to link the stream to it. This stream can be consumed by Lambda or a any other Kinesis consumer, like RedShift or KCL application.